# Wrong Answer in Paying Up(CodeChef)

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming

I'm solving a question on CodeChef which is basically subset sum problem.
When a mobster approaches you in a dark alley, he asks you for a specific amount of money. You are obliged to show him all the money that you have, but you only need to pay up if he can find a subset of your banknotes whose total value matches his demand. Since banknotes in Byteland can have any positive integer value smaller than one thousand you are quite likely to get off without paying.

Input:

The first line contains integer t, the number of test cases (about 100). Then t test cases follow. Each test case starts with n, the number of banknotes in your wallet, and m, the amount of money the muggers asked of you. Then n numbers follow, representing values of your banknotes. Your wallet does not hold more than 20 banknotes, and the value of a single banknote is never more than 1000.

Output:

For each test case output a single line with the word 'Yes' if there is a subset of your banknotes that sums to m, and 'No' otherwise.

Example

Input:

```
5
3 3
1
1
1
5 11
1
2
4
8
16
5 23
1
2
4
8
16
5 13
1
5
5
10
10
```

Output:

```
Yes
Yes
Yes
No
```

My Code:

```
for _ in range(int(input())):
    n,sum1 = map(int,input().split())
    arr = []
    for i in range(n):
        arr.append(int(input()))
    matrix = [[False for i in range(sum1+1)] for j in range(n+1)]
    for i in range(n+1):
        for j in range(sum1+1):
            if i==0:
                matrix[i][j] = False
            if j==0:
                matrix[i][j] = True
            if arr[i-1]<=j:
                matrix[i][j] = matrix[i-1][j-arr[i-1]] or matrix[i-1][j]
            elif arr[i-1]>j:
                matrix[i][j] = matrix[i-1][j]
    if matrix[n][sum1]==True:
        print("Yes")
    else:
        print("No")
```

Why am I getting Wrong Answer?

Edit:
This is the correct solution to Subset Sum Problem

```
n = len(A)

    # T[i][j] stores true if subset with sum j can be attained with
    # using items up to first i items
    T = [[False for x in range(sum + 1)] for y in range(n + 1)]

    # if sum is zero
    for i in range(n + 1):
        T[i][0] = True

    # do for ith item
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        # consider all sum from 1 to sum
        for j in range(1, sum + 1):
            # don't include ith element if j-A[i-1] is negative
            if A[i - 1] > j:
                T[i][j] = T[i - 1][j]
            else:
                # find subset with sum j by excluding or including the i'th item
                T[i][j] = T[i - 1][j] or T[i - 1][j - A[i - 1]]

    # return maximum value
    return T[n][sum]


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Input: set of items and a sum
    A = [7, 3, 2, 5, 8]
    sum = 18

    if subsetSum(A, sum):
        print("Yes")
    else:
        print("No")
```

If I initialized my DP list from the above approach it's giving me Correct Output. But I am not able to figure out what's the problem in my logic of intitalizing the DP list(`t` in my code).

Comment: I guess that if  `i == 0`, trying an access at `i-1` is undefined behavior

Comment: is this a live CodeChef competition question? guys, please refrain from giving solution, till it is clarified by OP

Comment: No, it is not a live CodeChef competition question. You can check.Question's name is Paying up and problem code is A1@sahasrara62